# Recovering old RDL files from previous SSRS instance

Tags: reporting-services, sql-server-2008-r2, ssrs-2008

So my problem is that on an already working instance of SQL Server 2008R2, a former colleague of mine installed a new instance, apparently with the same name and leaving us now with an empty Report Manager. The URL for the old one still works, but it only shows me the file structure for the old Report Manager.

Is there a way to somehow extract the old RDLs (considering it has no graphical interface anymore) so that I may load them to the new one? Or alternatively, set the ReportServer service to use the old instance in order to download the RDL files?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you start/restart the instances without causing too many issues in your environment?

Answer (score 1):

I can think about a couple of options:

**Download through Report Builder**

It sounds like the old ReportServer URL is available? That's something, at least.

One option that might have the least impact is connecting to the old ReportServer through Report Builder, opening the RDL files then saving them to the location of your choice.

Connect to the ReportServer:

[image]

Navigate and open the file you need.

[image]

Click **Save As** to save the RDL as required.

**Start/restart different instances**

Based on your description, it sounds like both instances are trying to register the same URL.

If possible, I would stop both instances, then restart the old instance which has the RDL files you want.

Hopefully this will allow the old instance to register its URLs successfully and allow you to connect to the old Report Manager URL and [download the RDL files](http://sql-articles.com/blogs/download-export-rdl-files-from-report-server/).

You can check the different URLs each instance is using through the Reporting Services Configuration Manager application:

[image]